# Sorry Something Went Wrong while building a query

Tags: search, display-template, query

I recently built a new SSA and performed a full crawl on all content sources, all search results appear to be fine, however when building a query, no matter what I put in or use I get the Error "Sorry, something went wrong" Search has encountered a problem that prevents results from being returned. If the issue persists, please contact your administrator.

I've found the Correlation ID and all its giving me is time out. [image]I am looking to build some display templates, but I cant get any results to display when building the query.

Also, crawls are performing well with no issues, I've tested to make sure new items are showing up in the search center and timer jobs perform crawls on schedules. There are also no errors in the crawl logs.

Comment: What was the query and where did you perform it?